# Ubuntu kernel killing java process even though it is not out of memory

Tags: java, linux, amazon-ec2, linux-kernel, out-of-memory

I have an ec2 instance with 48 cores and 192 GB memory and Ubuntu 18.04. I am running a java application on it where max memory is set to be 128 GB. In between the java application gets killed by the linux kernel. I connected JVisualVM and also the GC logs is saying that the Java VM is taking just 50GB heap at max. So why is Linux killing the java application? There is nothing else running on this machine just the application. I tried running dmesg and what I see is:

```
[166098.587603] Out of memory: Kill process 10273 (java) score 992 or sacrifice child
[166098.591428] Killed process 10273 (java) total-vm:287522172kB, anon-rss:191924060kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
[166104.034642] oom_reaper: reaped process 10273 (java), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

Comment: you can try disabling the oom reaper (killer)

Comment: You can also disable the over-commit policy used by Linux for virtual memory. Also see [Effects of configuring vm.overcommit_memory](https://serverfault.com/q/362589/145545). By the way, Solaris does not over subscribe memory. If an application asks for 100 GB of memory, then there will be 100 GB of virtual memory available or the allocation will fail. Solaris never experiences OOM kills after an allocation.

Answer (score 4):

The key thing to look at is `anon-rss:191924060kB`.  RSS is the [Resident set size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_set_size), which the Wikipedia article defines as

> the portion of memory occupied by a process that is held in main memory

Putting the commas in, 191,924,060kB is just short of 192Gb.  Of that, 50GB is the portion of Java's heap -- the space that Java uses for objects allocated at run-time -- that's actually in use.  The rest includes the JVM runtime, any libraries your program might be using, and of course your program itself.

The total virtual memory occupied by your program is 287.5GB; that presumably includes the other 78GB of the 128GB heap you've allocated.